Google Chrome Issues Version 127 Adding images to product
When I try to add an image to the product using the admin panel, only those images that will fit in the last line remain (if i change the screen width, the number of images will also change), all other images are not displayed. In previous versions of Chrome, everything worked correctly. Has anyone already solved this problem? Please share it.
magento 2.4.4, 2.4.5, 2.4.6, php 81. magento 2.4.7 works correct

Perhaps your customisation or a 3rd party script is using Mutation events, which has been removed from Chrome in v127.
https://developer.chrome.com/blog/mutation-events-deprecation
If there is any, you should migrate them all to MutationObserver.
You can check an example Magento does in vendor/magento/module-page-builder/view/adminhtml/web/js/resource/resize-observer/ResizeObserver.js:390

thanks for your answer, but there are no Mutation events in the code (except for the place you indicated and which is migrated)

For now I did
.gallery {
overflow: visible;}
But I don't like this decision
